# python/pandas transfer the dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have a pandas Dataframe like below
the columns are ['music_id', 'users_id', 'scores']

```
A       a       1
A       c       2
A       b       1
B       e       2
B       a       3
B       b       1
```

I try to make a new dataframe like this:

```
    a   b   c   e
A   1   1   2   Na
B   3   1   Na  2
```

Is there any method in pandas to make like this? 
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
df.set_index([0,1])[2].unstack()
```

output:

```
1    a    b    c    e
0                    
A  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
B  3.0  1.0  NaN  2.0
```

Getting rid of the axis names output:

```
df.set_index([0,1])[2].unstack().rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None)

     a    b    c    e
A  1.0  1.0  2.0  NaN
B  3.0  1.0  NaN  2.0
```

where, df:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  a  1
1  A  c  2
2  A  b  1
3  B  e  2
4  B  a  3
5  B  b  1
```